# How to drag more than one JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextpane

I have created a frame with `null` layout, and I have 6 small `JTextPane`s in it. My intention is when I clicked a particular `textpane`, it has to get dragged by mouse wherever I want in the frame.

Comment: You should try something before coming here... Questions should be more specific.

Comment: That oesnt make sense, what you mean by high liter and dragged?

Comment: i want a particular textpane to be dragged when clicked by mouse in java. what i want exactly is how to know a particular text pane is clicked so that i  able to drag by using mouse using mouse listener events in java making remaining textpanes fixed

Comment: @AnanthBommakanty you should post an SSCCE to show what you tried

Comment: k i had 6 labels in my jframe. now if i select a label it have to be dragged when i drag it by mouse remaining labels making unchanged.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `null` layout, consider six instances of [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), each containing a `JTextPane`. An enclosing `JDesktopPane` derives from `JLayeredPane`, which manages its `null` layout implicitly.